# cut off a function mid-plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple problem I can't seem to find an answer to.

I'm plotting the below function p, where there is a constraint m≧0.

Consequently, I want to plot the function p only in the domain m∈[0,∞).

```r
p <- function(m) (-m^2+9*m+1)/(1+m)
xrange <- c(-10, 10)
yrange <- c(-20,20)
plot(p, xlim=xrange, ylim=yrange)
```

How do I cut off the plot from m<0?

Comment: `curve(p, from = 0, to = 20)`.

Comment: Or `curve(p, from = 0, to = 20, xlim = xrange, ylim = yrange)`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. @RuiBarradas